# How to dynamically resize image in tinyMCE editor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE editor. However, I have run into a problem. I can add the image and resize it as well but when I resize, both height and width get resized by same proportion.

I want to resize only height without affecting the width and vice-versa. The only way I can do this is by hardcoding width and height values which is pretty tedious job.  How to fix it?

When I resize both height and width gets resized, no option to resize them separately

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unlock the width and height by clicking on the the lock button

[image: Edit box]